# Changing app requirements

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-play

How can I view and manage requirements of my app (API version is obvious and is in Manifest), but how about having GPS, phone module, and so on?

Can I publish in Google play same app but for example for phones with LTE (something like same app for different API)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using filters in your manifest (see links referenced below), you can use elements like `<uses-configuration>`, `<uses-feature>`, `<uses-library>`, and `<uses-sdk>` to specify which features your app requires in order to run.

You can publish your most "advanced" version of your app on Google Play and give it the highest `android:versionCode`, and then publish a "less-advanced" version with less filters and a lower `android:versionCode` value.  Devices that Google Play thinks can utilize the most advanced version will receive that APK, and others will receive the lesser one.

Check these links for more information:

- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html
- http://developer.android.com/google/play/filters.html
- http://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html